# Fetch data from nested JSON API in SwiftUI (object in array in object in another object)

Tags: json, api, object, swiftui, nested

Beginner here, in a bit over my head with this. ;)

I've found examples that have shown me how to get data from a JSON API feed if the feed is structured as an array of objects, but I don't know how to approach getting the data (specifically, **url** and **title**) if the data I'm retrieving comes back in a more complex nested structure like this one:

```
{
    "races": {
        "videos": [{
            "id": 1,
            "url": "firsturl",
            "title": "1st Video Title"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "url": "secondurl",
            "title": "2nd Video Title"
        }]
    }
}
```

I've succeeded at get data from another API feed that's structured as a simple array of objects--it's like what's above but without the extra two lead-in objects, namely this: **{ "races": { "videos":**

Here's the code I pieced together from a few examples that worked for the simple array:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Video: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id: Int
    public var url: String
    public var title: String
}

class Videos: ObservableObject {
  @Published var videos = [Video]()
     
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://exampledomain.com/jsonapi")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let videoData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Video].self, from: videoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.videos = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("no data found")
                }
            } catch {
                print("an error occurred")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct VideosView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = Videos()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.videos) { video in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(video.title)
                    Text("\(video.url)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've spent several hours over a few days reading and watching tutorials, but so far nothing is sinking in to help me tackle the more complex JSON API feed. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

With the help of a Swift Playground tutorial and the suggested structs mentioned in the comments below, I've succeeded at retrieving the more complex data, but only in Swift Playgrounds, using this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Welcome: Codable {
    let races: Races
}

struct Races: Codable {
    let videos: [Video]
}

struct Video: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url, title: String
}

func getJSON<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(decodedData)
    }.resume()
}

getJSON(urlString: "https://not-the-real-domain.123/api/") { (followers:Welcome?) in
    if let followers = followers {
        for result in followers.races.videos {
            print(result.title )
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm struggling with how to properly integrate this Playgrounds snippet in to the working SwiftUI file's VideosViews, etc.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Welcome: Codable {
    let races: RaceItem
}

struct RaceItem: Codable {
    let videos: [VideoItem]
}

struct VideoItem: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
    let title: String
}

class Fetcher: ObservableObject {
    func getJSON<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(decodedData)
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct JSONRacesView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fetch = Fetcher()
    
    getJSON(urlString:"https://not-the-real-domain.123/api/") { (followers:Welcome?) in
        if let followers = followers {
            for result in followers.races.videos {
                print(result.title )
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.tracks) { track in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(track.title)
                    Text("\(track.url)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a great site called QuickType (app.quicktype.io) where you can paste in some JSON and get the Swift structs generated for you. Here's what it gives you:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let races: Races
}

// MARK: - Races
struct Races: Codable {
    let videos: [Video]
}

// MARK: - Video
struct Video: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url, title: String
}
```

They have a bug in their template generator that mangles the demo line (I've submitted a pull request that is merged but isn't live on the site at the time of this writing), but here's what it should look like:

```
let welcome = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
```

Using `do/try` so you can catch the errors, you can decode the data and reach the lower levels by doing:

```
do {
  let welcome = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
  let videos = welcome.races.videos //<-- this ends up being your [Video] array
} catch {
  //handle any errors
}
```

---

**Update, based on your comments and updates**:
You chose to go a little bit of a different route than my initial suggestion, but that's fine. The only thing that I would suggest is that you might want to deal with handling errors at some point rather than just returning `nil` in all of the completions (assuming you need to handle errors -- maybe it just not loading is acceptable).

Here's a light refactor of your code:

```
class Fetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tracks : [VideoItem] = []
    
    private func getJSON<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(decodedData)
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        getJSON(urlString:"https://not-the-real-domain.123/api/") { (followers:Welcome?) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tracks = followers?.races.videos ?? []
            }
        }
    }
}

struct JSONRacesView: View {
    @StateObject var fetch = Fetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.tracks, id: \.id) { track in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(track.title)
                    Text("\(track.url)")
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            fetch.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that now `Fetcher` has a `@Published` property that will store the tracks ([VideoItem]). `getJSON` is still in fetcher, but now it's `private` just to show that it isn't meant to be called directly. But, now there's a new function called `fetchData()` that your view will call. When `fetchData` gets data back, it sets the @Published property to that data. I used the `??` operator to tell the compiler that if `followers` is nil, then just use `[]` instead. This is all in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block because the URL call is probably not going to return on the main thread and we need to make sure to always update the UI on the main thread (Xcode will warn you about this at runtime if you update the UI on a different thread).

`JSONRacesView` calls `fetchData` in `onAppear`, which happens exactly when it sounds like it will.

Last thing to note is I used `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`. If you're not on iOS 14 or macOS 11 yet, you could use @ObservedObject instead. There are some differences outside the scope of this answer, but that are easily Google-able.

Comment: Thanks for recommending QuickType. I had tried that site previously but had a hard time figuring out how to put all the pieces together into a real SwiftUI project. I ended up getting something to work by combining your QuickType struct suggestions with a Swift Playground tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivFtzG8Bqkk&t=0s) that used a different approach, but I'm struggling with how to turn the playground into a proper SwiftUI file. Going to read some more...

Comment: Okay, I updated my question with more data to show some additional progress (if I can call it that). ;)

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is. You know how to get the data and decode it. Can't you just put your  `getJSON` func in your `ObservableObject` and then set `self.videos` to the result once you've decoded it: `self.videos = followers.races.videos`?

Comment: I did manage to figure out that I needed to embed the getJSON function into the ObservableObject, but in trying to put the function call "getJSON(urlString..." into the SwiftUI View, I'm getting all kinds of errors, so I imagine either it's in the wrong place or there's some other things I'm not comprehending. As I said, I think I'm in a bit over my head, having just started learning to program in January. I'll post what I've assembled above as "Update 2".

Comment: You can't call `getJSON` outside of a function like that. I'll post a modification of your code momentarily

Comment: Wow—this worked! Okay, now I can use tomorrow to look into the different parts of the refactor to see what they accomplish, and can Google a few more things to make sure I comprehend all of the explanation that you shared, which I really appreciate! Also, I saw the sax in your user thumbnail and clicked through to find your website—great music! (I'm a jazz fan, maybe marginally better on piano than coding)! :) Thanks again!

Comment: Wonderful -- glad it worked for you. Feel free to check out the music apps :)

Comment: Yeah, they look really neat!